# how to stop 20.04 LTS from managing moz firefox updates

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, firefox

I just upgraded a workstation from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS over the web.  I use Mozilla Firefox production download tar.bz2, not a .deb from an Ubuntu repository.  The upgrade automatically installed the Ubuntu version of Firefox.  I manually removed this Ubuntu-automatically installed version with apt purge and the like, although before doing so I did, as root, `mv /usr/lib/firefox /usr/lib/firefox-distro` so that the Ubuntu version can be accessed.  In the Mozilla production version, when I select within Mozilla Help -> About Firefox, the "check for updates" box appears, but cannot be activated, and the usual check with "Firefox up to date" (after an automatic checking by Firefox and unless an update is needed) does *NOT* appear.  From

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-release?redirectslug=update-firefox-latest-version&redirectlocale=en-US

> Note: If you use your Linux distribution's packaged version of
> Firefox, you will need to wait for an updated package to be released
> to its package repository. This article only applies if you installed
> Firefox manually (without using your distribution's package manager).

End excerpt.

How to I get Firefox *NOT* to be under the update control of the "distribution's package manager"?

Comment: I do not understand what you did. A manually installed version outside of the APT system will not be automatically updated, and should normally not even be reinstalled on a dist-upgrade.

Comment: Somehow, on the upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, the Ubuntu version of Firefox was installed; this Ubuntu version also was automatically installed when 18.04 LTS originally was installed as there was no (obvious) switch/file list not to install the distro version of Firefox.  On my machine, a 20.04 LTS, I re-installed (from a separate backup copy) ~/.mozilla from my SL 7 home directory (for SL, I did not accept the distro version just as I do not from Ubuntu LTS).  There must be some setting different from SL.  The issue is not with my machine.